# I added a logo using an "img" tag. This caused my embedded website drop down to no longer scroll. I used an iframe tag to embed the other website

Tags: html, css, iframe

I recently added a logo to my website in the bottom right corner using a "img" tag. For some reason this caused my embedded drop down website to no longer be able to scroll. Anytime i try to scroll it just highlights the logo i added. I used an iframe tag to embed the website in a drop down. Code i used below.

embedded drop down code:

```
<div class="holder"><iframe class="iframe" src="mission statement.html"></iframe><div class="bar"></div>
</div>
CSS:.iframe {position: absolute; top: 300px;}
```

interfering logo code:

```
<div class="holder"> <img class="img" src="Gary Logo Finial Size test (1).jpg"> <div class="bar"></div></div>
CSS:.holder{
   width: 450px;
   height:300px;
   position:relative;}
.frame{
   width: 100%;
   height:100%;}
.bar{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:40px;}
   .img {position: absolute; top: 500px; left: 1750px; height: 50%;}
```

Div tags are used for making the images appear on top of my background. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it Out! Turns out the "holder" tag was being used by both the img and iframe tag. Thats why i couldn't scroll anymore. I just simply removed class="holder" from the img code.